# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.1 no desktop or network

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04, upgrade, .desktop

I upgraded and when I checked it had issues booting, so I rebooted, and I got the menu to select Ubuntu or memory checks etc and chose Ubuntu. it first booted to login for 14.04 and said last login July 2016??? So I rebooted and again got to login prompt that said 16.04.1 last loging todays date. so I was happier. But no desktop. I try and do apt-get update to finish update but got errors because my network was not up. SO now I guess I need help getting an ip address and internet. I tried to restart network and manager but errors. ifconfig reports no IP address, which should be 192.168.0.3. I tried adding ip but get error saying gatway not found. Not sure how to get the desktop to load or if it was installed. I thought I should get network working first, then finish or check updates. But I need help with networking please. Any help appreciated.

Update:
I now have an IP address!! on eth0 and I was able to ssh in remotely. Still have errors when I run apt-get update. I see:

```
    norman@merlin:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for norman: 
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.canonical.com xenial Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease
```

Here is ifconfig results:

```
norman@merlin:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:17:2d:3a:ce  
          inet addr:192.168.0.3  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:17ff:fe2d:3ace/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7389 (7.3 KB)  TX bytes:15389 (15.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:99664 (99.6 KB)  TX bytes:99664 (99.6 KB)
```

Comment: Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this seems for wireless. I have always and am just trying to fix a system whee I am using wired ethernet connection. No wireless. it just broke due to upgrade failure and I want to fix it and not connect another way. Makes sense? How do I un-foobar what the upgrade did. My files are there but its like the upgrade broke and i dont have all the required system files. Is there a way to install a 16.04.1 cd and repair or something?

Comment: The diagnostics provide excellent information about wired network connections too. I suspect that this is a simple device driver or networking configuration issue. If you have a new or follow-up question please open a [new question](/questions/ask). The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.

Comment: just for the record I have decided to just reinstall from scratch and consider this a botched upgrade. Upgrades to me should at least reload a working system. thanks anyway guys. No need for more answers. Not deleting.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @ElderGreek No, I have decided to reinstall, as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you have more than one screen for your desktop?  I do and seem to face these sorts of issues every time I install a new release...

I faced similar issues, but not the network ones... basically Unity had to be started after a basic X restart to give me a usable system (otherwise I only had a wallpaper and a mouse cursor!).

My recipe to fix this was to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> to give me a TTY screen with command line where I can logon.  Then a simple `startx unity` will get X started and gives me a basic, but unsatisfactory system.  So `<CTRL> C` from the X terminal to leave that and you should fall back to the TTY terminal.

Follow that with `sudo service lightdm start` and I was good to go.  Next use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f7</kbd> to return from tty screen to my Unity session.

Liberal use of the "Suspend" function might stop this being too much of a pain, because it is far from ideal, more a workaround than a solution.  Also, and I cannot explain this, it will not always work for me - seems to work about 3 times out of four.  Another shortcoming is that with this desktop I'm unable to drag anything onto it, nor does Rubbish bin or any mounted drive show up there.

I was going to make my own post asking how I can get boot to incorporate the starting of unity and subsequent service start, but this was so close to my symptoms I thought I would share - hopefully it works for you?

Even more hopefully someone with a deeper understanding of X and lightdm screenmanager can identify a way forward for a proper solution which might make its way into updates soon!